# NameNotFoundException когда перезапускаю модуль в weblogic

Tags: java, dependency-injection, ejb, weblogic

Всем привет. Столкнулся с проблемой при работе с weblogic и EJB.

При развороте модуля на сервере все работает корректно, после этого с консоли останавливаю модуль и заново его стартую. После вызова любого функционала данного модуля получаю ошибку javax.naming.NameNotFoundException.

Хотелось бы понять почему возникает подобная ситуация?

Весь стектрейс ошибки тут:

```
2018-03-09 09:41:40,343 ERROR U:n/a  ReqId:39e5a1b2-0936-4820-a72c-d80a6053fe4b ThrowableExceptionMapper toResponse - ERR: Internal server error, something went unexpectedly wrong.
javax.enterprise.inject.InjectionException: Exception trying to inject java EE injection point into class: com.medtronic.diabetes.carelink.dataupload.hcp.resource.impl.SnapshotResourceImpl.
    at com.oracle.injection.integration.ModuleContainerIntegrationService.performJavaEEInjection(ModuleContainerIntegrationService.java:405)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)
Caused by: com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Dependency injection failure: can't find the bean definition about class interface com.medtronic.diabetes.carelink.dataupload.hcp.service.UploaderTokenService; nested exception is com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [com.medtronic.diabetes.carelink.dataupload.hcp.service.UploaderTokenService] is defined: No beans of type com.medtronic.diabetes.carelink.dataupload.hcp.service.UploaderTokenService; owner=com.oracle.pitchfork.inject.PitchforkGenericApplicationContext@2daab968: display name [com.oracle.pitchfork.inject.PitchforkGenericApplicationContext@2daab968]; startup date [Fri Mar 09 08:39:55 UTC 2018]; parent: com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@5fe15374; nested exception is com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'hcpUploaderTokenServiceImpl' is defined; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to look up comp/env/hcpUploaderTokenServiceImpl in /app/webapp/api/uploader/v1/961601745.; remaining name 'comp/env/hcpUploaderTokenServiceImpl'
    at com.oracle.pitchfork.inject.Jsr250Metadata.applyInjections(Jsr250Metadata.java:218)
    at com.oracle.injection.integration.ModuleContainerIntegrationService.performJavaEEInjection(ModuleContainerIntegrationService.java:398)
    ... 65 more
Caused by: com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [com.medtronic.diabetes.carelink.dataupload.hcp.service.UploaderTokenService] is defined: No beans of type com.medtronic.diabetes.carelink.dataupload.hcp.service.UploaderTokenService; owner=com.oracle.pitchfork.inject.PitchforkGenericApplicationContext@2daab968: display name [com.oracle.pitchfork.inject.PitchforkGenericApplicationContext@2daab968]; startup date [Fri Mar 09 08:39:55 UTC 2018]; parent: com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@5fe15374; nested exception is com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'hcpUploaderTokenServiceImpl' is defined; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to look up comp/env/hcpUploaderTokenServiceImpl in /app/webapp/api/uploader/v1/961601745.; remaining name 'comp/env/hcpUploaderTokenServiceImpl'
    at com.oracle.pitchfork.inject.Jsr250Metadata.getUniqueInstanceOfType(Jsr250Metadata.java:348)
    at com.oracle.pitchfork.inject.Jsr250Metadata.applyInjections(Jsr250Metadata.java:215)
    ... 67 more
Caused by: com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'hcpUploaderTokenServiceImpl' is defined; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to look up comp/env/hcpUploaderTokenServiceImpl in /app/webapp/api/uploader/v1/961601745.; remaining name 'comp/env/hcpUploaderTokenServiceImpl'
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:387)
    at com.oracle.pitchfork.inject.Jsr250Metadata.resolve(Jsr250Metadata.java:265)
    ... 68 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to look up comp/env/hcpUploaderTokenServiceImpl in /app/webapp/api/uploader/v1/961601745.; remaining name 'comp/env/hcpUploaderTokenServiceImpl'
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.newNameNotFoundException(BasicNamingNode.java:1224)
    at com.oracle.pitchfork.inject.Jsr250Metadata.resolve(Jsr250Metadata.java:258)
    ... 68 more
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Нашел решение этой проблемы путем маппинга моих классов в файле web.xml
Возможно это баг weblogic

На каждую аннотацию типа @Stateless(name = classNameImpl) добаил такой мапинг

```
<ejb-local-ref>
   <ejb-ref-name>classNameImpl</ejb-ref-name>
   <ejb-ref-type>Session</ejb-ref-type>        
   <local>com.adress.className</local>
   <ejb-link>classNameImpl</ejb-link>
</ejb-local-ref>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, дополните ответ. Как выглядит маппинг классов теперь?